# How to get a count of returned rows from PSObject array

Tags: powershell, count, psobject

I'm trying to provide a count of the rows in a PSObject array. I only get "0" even if I get results returned in an out-grid view.

```
Try{
    $Updates = Invoke-Command -cn $Servers {
        $Application =  Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\ccm\clientsdk" -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdate 
        If(!$Application){
                $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{      
                        ArticleId         = " - "
                        Publisher         = " - "
                        Software          = " - "
                        State             = " - "
                        StartTime         = " - "
                        DeadLine          = " - "
                })
  
                $Object
        }
        Else{
            Foreach ($App in $Application){
                
                $EvState = Switch ( $App.EvaluationState  ) {
                        '0'  { "None" } 
                        '1'  { "Available" } 
                        '2'  { "Submitted" } 
                        '3'  { "Detecting" } 
                        '4'  { "PreDownload" } 
                        '5'  { "Downloading" } 
                        '6'  { "WaitInstall" } 
                        '7'  { "Installing" } 
                        '8'  { "PendingSoftReboot" } 
                        '9'  { "PendingHardReboot" } 
                        '10' { "WaitReboot" } 
                        '11' { "Verifying" } 
                        '12' { "InstallComplete" } 
                        '13' { "Error" } 
                        '14' { "WaitServiceWindow" } 
                        '15' { "WaitUserLogon" } 
                        '16' { "WaitUserLogoff" } 
                        '17' { "WaitJobUserLogon" } 
                        '18' { "WaitUserReconnect" } 
                        '19' { "PendingUserLogoff" } 
                        '20' { "PendingUpdate" } 
                        '21' { "WaitingRetry" } 
                        '22' { "WaitPresModeOff" } 
                        '23' { "WaitForOrchestration" } 
  
  
                        DEFAULT { "Unknown" }
                }
            
                $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{      
                        ArticleId         = $App.ArticleID
                        Publisher         = $App.Publisher
                        Software          = $App.Name
                        State             = $EvState
                        StartTime         = Get-Date ([system.management.managementdatetimeconverter]::todatetime($($App.StartTime)))
                        DeadLine          = Get-Date ([system.management.managementdatetimeconverter]::todatetime($($App.Deadline)))
                         
                })
           
                $Object
            }
        }
  
    } -ErrorAction Continue | select @{n='ServerName';e={$_.pscomputername}},ArticleID,Publisher,Software,State,StartTime,DeadLine
}
Catch [System.Exception]{
    Write-Host "Error" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $_.Exception.Message
}


if (!$updates.Software.Contains("KB")) {
    $returnStatus.Text = "No Updates Found!"
    }
        Else { 
    $returnStatus.Text = "Results Found!"+ ($updatesPSObject.Properties | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Count")
    $Updates | Out-GridView -Title "Updates"
    }type here
```

After doing some reading here on Stackoverflow, I've found and tried the following statements as well, however they all simply return 0.

```
    $updatesPSObject.Properties | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Count")
    $updatesPSObject.Properties.value.Count
    $updatesPSObject.Properties.names.Count
    $updates.Count$updates|measure
```

The Out-Gridview does return results, however, I'd like to be able to provide a quick total count of the rows and GridView does not show that.

```
 $Updates | Out-GridView -Title "Updates"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: `$updatesPSObject` is not defined or assigned to anywhere in your script - so 0 makes sense, there's nothing to be measured :) Did you mean to write `$updates.PSObject` instead?

Comment: `$Updates.Count` should give you the number of elements.